# Laravel 6 onDelete->('set null') not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm having a weird error with my CRUD application. The `onUpdate->('cascade')` works but not for `onDelete->('set null')`. It works if I manually delete it in the database, but not for using the delete operation in the controller. Please see my migration file below.

```php
class CreatePositionsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('positions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('department_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments')
                ->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('section_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('sections')
                ->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('position_name', 100);
            $table->string('n_level', 10)->nullable();
            $table->string('job_description')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('positions');
    }
}
```

My Model if this affects anything.

**Positions.php**

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Iatstuti\Database\Support\CascadeSoftDeletes; //composer require iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes

use App\SalaryMatrix;
use App\Employee;

class Position extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['department_id', 'section_id', 'position_name', 'n_level', 'job_description'];

    use SoftDeletes, CascadeSoftDeletes;
    protected $softCascade = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $cascadeDeletes = ['salaryMatrix', 'employee'];

    public function department () {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
    }

    public function section () {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
    }

    public function salaryMatrix() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\SalaryMatrix', 'position_id');
    }

    public function employee() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee', 'position_id');
    }
}
```

**PositionController.php**

```
 public function destroy($id) {
    $position = Position::findOrFail($id);
    $position->delete();
  }
```

NOTE: This project is only deployed in localhost.

Comment: Please show how you delete the row

Comment: Hello sir mrhn. I have now posted my controller.

Comment: But the cascading set null should not work when you delete the position, can you show me how it works with updating?

Comment: Cascading is for updating the Department_id, you delete the position nothing should happen. On update makes no sense either, as it only when trigger if the Id is changed. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: When I update a record, the new value is updated to it's hasMany relationship. So it means that the onUpdate->('cascade') works. I'm trying to achieve that when I delete a department or section row, the department_id or section_id on table positions should be null. It works when I delete it in the database (using HeidiSQL), but if I used the delete method indicated in the controller, it also softcascade deletes the position who has a relationship with the deleted department / section.